# Postfix, dovecot error in one email account aliases

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have set up Postfix, dovecot in a vps everything is fine except if I send an email from account2@example.com is like I am sending from account1@example.com and also if I send an email from whatever I am receiving account2@example.com in account1@example.com.

I understand that is a alias or something but i have check all aliases folders, virtual folders and i don't see any redirect, alias, etc

Ho can revert this, i just want send and receive emails from account1@example.com
If someaccount1 can help i appreciate it, thaks a lot
Sorry for my poor english
I'm not familiar with Postfix, Dovecot

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Apr 21 15:12:33 mail postfix/lmtp[482771]: BE1D2BD0E9: to=<account1@example>, orig_to=<account2@example>, relay=example[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=4.6, delays=4.6/0/0.01/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <account1@example> vqyCCeFAgGDUXQcA3U33Jw Saved)
```

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
mydestination = mail.example.com, example.com, localhost.example.com, , localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydomain
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtputf8_enable = no


/etc/aliases
postmaster:    root
clamav: root


/etc/postfix/virtual
nothing
```

Comment: Does the account name in question contain your `recipient_delimiter` (your config says, that is a `+` sign)

Comment: Thanks for reply, where i can check it,